# Why Is My Color Palette Showing Up Incorrectly?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I created a color palette for a character I'm creating so that I can export into unity. When I added my image texture to blender, it showed up with a sort of green filter. Currently using blender 2.91 right now and I'm not too sure what to do

In Blender

[image]

Original Image[image: Original Image]

Comment: Take a look at the Render panel > Color Management > View Transform, make sure you've selected Standard and not Filmic, maybe it's your problem? If it doesn't fix it, please pack your image and share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/